# Transformation of quadratic form

Tags: analysis, quadratic-forms

I've got the following quadratic form

> > $T(x_1,x_2)=x^TQx$, with 
> >     $$
> > x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}, Q=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)L_1^2 & \frac{1}{2} m_2L_1L_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\\\frac{1}{2} m_2L_1L_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) & \frac{1}{2}m_2 L_2^2\end{pmatrix}.
> > $$
> >     $Q$ is positive definit.

(This all is deduced from a double pendulum which upper bob has mass $m_1$ and the angle $\theta_1$ with length $L_1$ and lower bob has mass $m_2$, angle $\theta_2$ and length $L_2$.)

Now the task is to make a "Hauptachsentransformation" (sorry, I do not know the correct english word for that!). Maybe "mean axis transformation"? I think the result is that one can see better that it is an ellipse?

I think the first step is to determine the eigenvalues of $Q$, right?

I got
$$
\lambda_1=-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{c^2-4d}-c), \lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{c^2-4d}+c)
$$
with
$$
c:=\frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)L_2^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2L_2^2,
$$
$$
d:=\frac{1}{4}m_2(m_1+m_2)L_2^4-\frac{1}{4}m_2^2L_1^2L_2^2\cos^2(\theta_1-\theta_2).
$$

I think now in the next step I have to determine the eigenvectors but to be honest I do not know how to do it here...

I never did a "Hauptachsentransformation" before...

Comment: I think the meaning is, perhaps, to express the quadratic form as a sum and difference of squares?

Comment: The background is the following. T, expressed as a sum, is bounded.   Now I would like to show that for fixed $\theta_1,\theta_2$ the the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are bounded, too. I thought I have to make this to show that.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix you have is of the form
$$
                  Q = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\ c & b\end{array}\right].
$$
So the quadratic form $x^{T}Qx$ has the form
$$
                 T(x_{1},x_{2})=ax_{1}^{2}+2cx_{1}x_{2}+bx_{2}^{2}.
$$
There's a big short-cut you can take when dealing with a $2\times 2$ matrix.
What you're trying to do is rotate the coordinate system until the cross term disappears. The standard technique is a rotation where you set
$$
\begin{align}
        x_{1}+ix_{2} & = (x_{1}'+ix_{2}')(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) \\
                     & = (x_{1}'\cos\theta-x_{2}'\sin\theta)+i(x_{1}'\sin\theta+x_{2}'\cos\theta)
\end{align}
$$
That is, $x_{1}=x_{1}'\cos\theta-x_{2}'\sin\theta$ and $x_{2}=x_{1}'\sin\theta+x_{2}'\cos\theta$. Plug this in to get
$$
\begin{align}
    T(x_{1},x_{2}) & =a(x_{1}'\cos\theta-x_{2}'\sin\theta)^{2} \\
         & +2c(x_{1}'\cos\theta-x_{2}'\sin\theta)(x_{1}'\sin\theta+x_{2}'\cos\theta) \\
         & +b(x_{1}'\sin\theta+x_{2}'\cos\theta)^{2}.
\end{align}
$$
The cross terms $x_{1}'x_{2}'$ disappear when $\theta$ is chosen to satisfy
$$
    -a\cos\theta\sin\theta +c(\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta)+b\sin\theta\cos\theta = 0.
$$
Then the matrix
$$
                P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
                        \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
                        \sin\theta &  \cos\theta
                        \end{array}\right]
$$
is orthogonal ($P^{T}=P^{-1}$) and gives $P^{T}QP$ equal to a diagonal matrix.